# How to find the max value of an Arraylist and two of its Index position using Java

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I find the maximum value from an `Arraylist` with its index positions?

```
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
ar.add(2); // position 0
ar.add(4); // position 1
ar.add(12); // position 2
ar.add(10); // position 3
ar.add(12); // position 4

String obj = Collections.max(ar);
int index = ar.indexOf(obj);

System.out.println("obj max value is " + obj + " and index position is " + index);
```

The above program just returns the output as the first max object with value `12` and index position `2`.

But my actual output should be index positions `2` and `4` (because max value `12` is present in two index position).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read the [FAQ] and [ask].  Also, you have asked 13 questions and accepted ZERO answers.  Please go back and accept some answers.

Comment: Why  don't you simply use a `for` loop  for iterating through the list by using `.get(i)` for getting each list element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```java
public static int maxIndex(List<Integer> list) {
  Integer i=0, maxIndex=-1, max=null;
  for (Integer x : list) {
    if ((x!=null) && ((max==null) || (x>max))) {
      max = x;
      maxIndex = i;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return maxIndex
}
// ...
maxIndex(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 2, 1)); // => 2
maxIndex(Arrays.asList(null, null)); // => -1
maxIndex(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // => -1
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use **Collections** to find the max value of a list, and then use the property **indexOf** to find its position in your list.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(3); // adding some values
myList.add(5);
myList.add(7);
myList.add(3);
myList.add(1);

Integer maxVal = Collections.max(myList); // should return 7
Integer maxIdx = myList.indexOf(maxVal); // should return 2 (position of the value 7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8 this could be done by:

```java
int index = IntStream.range(0, ar.size()).boxed()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(ar::get)).orElse(-1);
```

Comment: This is the coolest answer! can you please explain your solution?

Comment: @likejudo, the idea is straightforward: I get all indices of the given `ArrayList` (`IntStream.range(0, ar.size())`), then box them (getting `Stream<Integer`) to be able to use comparator, and take a max index comparing not themselves, but getting elements from the given `ArrayList` at them. The result of `max` is `Optional`, so that in the case of empty input, I'll get `Optional.empty()` result. In this case, I'll return `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate once through list, have another list to push index of maximum number

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args){

```
    List<Integer> ar=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ar.add(2); `adding the values in the list`
    ar.add(5);
    ar.add(6);
    ar.add(4);
    ar.add(6);
    ar.add(5);
    ar.add(6);

    int max=Collections.max(ar);

    while(ar.contains(max))
    {
        int i=ar.indexOf(max); 
        System.out.println("the index of 6:"+ar.indexOf(max));
        ar.set(i, -1);
        System.out.println(ar);
    }
```

}