# get the position of an element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public long getMax() // get maximum value
{
    if (nelems == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    long lngMax = arr[0];
    for (int j = 1; j < nelems; j++) {
        if (lngMax < arr[j]) {
            lngMax = arr[j];
        }
    }
    return lngMax;
}
```

This method returns the maximum value in an array .what logic i should write here that instead of returning value it returns the position of the maximum value without using any in-built method in java?
and sorry for asking silly question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the max value of an arraylist and two of its Index position using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437623/how-to-find-the-max-value-of-an-arraylist-and-two-of-its-index-position-using-ja)

Comment: @Joe i already mentioned no built-in methods

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public int getMax() // get maximum value
{
    int index = -1;
    if (nelems == 0) {
    return -1;
}
   long lngMax = arr[0];
   for (int j = 1; j < nelems; j++) {
       if (lngMax < arr[j]) {
           lngMax = arr[j];
           index = j;
       }
   }
   return index;
}
```

Just keep track of the index of the largest element then return an int instead of a long and return the index.

Answer (score 2):

With minimal changes you can do:

```
public long getIndexOfMaxValue() {
    if (nelems == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    long result = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < nelems; j++) {
        if (arr[result] < arr[j]) {
            result = j;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you put `result = j` instead of `result = arr[j]` since he wants the position?

Comment: what's the point of result type long? index `j` won't be larger than INT_MAX anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
public int getMaxInd() // get maximum value
{
    if (nelems == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    long lngMax = arr[0]
    int lngMaxInd = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < nelems; j++) {
        if (lngMax < arr[j]) {
            lngMax = arr[j];
            lngMaxInd = j;
        }
    }
    return lngMaxInd;
}
```

Comment: Really you think you can access j out site the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code, change to this:

```
public int getMaxIndex() 
{
    if (nelems == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    long lngMax = arr[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < nelems; j++) {
        if (lngMax < arr[j]) {
            lngMax = arr[j];
            index = j;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: @wrongAnswer Do not really need, but I think it is better to use it instead of accessing `arr[index]` on each iteration.

Comment: @eis Short answer: I think it is better (for performance) in case of large arrays because accessing `arr[index]` is more expensive than accessing only `index` if `arr[index]` block is not in your CPU cache.